# Object selection in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to select a gameobject at run time in unity and move it using an UI button.
for example if there are three cubes in the scene i want to select  one cube and one that I clicked will move once I click the UI button .

I have no idea how to pass the value of the selected object to the button click event.If some one can show it using a sample code it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag on the object and then use the `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()` function to get that object.

Here is the documentation for the function: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Comment: You can also set a tag with `GameObject.tag` or you can do it within the UI. Select the GameObject and there should be a field on the Object Properties up the top that is "tag" that you can set with a predefined tag or your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var obj = Selection.activeObject;
```

When working with objects that are primarily in a scene, it is strongly recommended to use below code instead:

```
var transform = Selection.activeTransform;
```

Refer to official doc [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-activeObject.html).